# Updating all keys of a nested dictionary from another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have the following nested dictionary with around 1000 keys:

```
net_info = {
            '17052242':{'lengthkm': 1.555787, 'uparea': 123.23709555834532, 'order': 2,
                        'strmDrop_t': 231.5, 'unitarea': 123.23709555834532},
            '21009006':{'lengthkm': 6.677901703662528,'uparea': 493.8188826654188,
                        'order': 2,'strmDrop_t': 5.3, 'unitarea': 36.89608111068623},
            .
            .
            .
             }
```

I would like to add a new "feature" called `"Q"` that I calculated using a predefined function that uses the value of the `'uparea'` that already exists inside the dictionary. Is there a fast way to do this? I will be adding the `Q` for all the existing keys, there are no new keys.

An example of the function of the `'Q'` would be:

```
def discharge(a):
    return 0.0229*pow(a,0.8781)
```

What I hope to obtain is:

```
net_info = {
            '17052242':{'lengthkm': 1.555787, 'uparea': 123.23709555834532, 'order': 2,
                        'strmDrop_t': 231.5, 'unitarea': 123.23709555834532,
                        'Q': 1.569334612348277},
            '21009006':{'lengthkm': 6.677901703662528,'uparea': 493.8188826654188,
                        'order': 2, 'strmDrop_t': 5.3, 'unitarea': 36.89608111068623,
                        'Q': 5.309544598741915},
            .
            .
            .
             }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for x in net_info.values():
    x["Q"] = discharge(x["uparea"])
```

This changes each value inside `net_info` because they're dicts - `x` is a reference to a dictionary, not a copy of it. If `net_info`'s values were simple types like `int` this wouldn't work.

Comment: In other words, this only works for dictionaries with mutable values.

Answer (score 2):

You can just loop through your `dict` -

```
net_info = {
    '17052242': {'lengthkm': 1.555787, 'uparea': 123.23709555834532, 'order': 2,
                 'strmDrop_t': 231.5, 'unitarea': 123.23709555834532},
    '21009006': {'lengthkm': 6.677901703662528, 'uparea': 493.8188826654188,
                 'order': 2, 'strmDrop_t': 5.3, 'unitarea': 36.89608111068623}
}


def discharge(a):
    return 0.0229*pow(a, 0.8781)


for k in net_info:
    net_info[k]['Q'] = discharge(net_info[k]['uparea']) # beware if the `uparea` key is missing, use dict.get(key, default) instead.

print(net_info)
```

outputs -

```
{'17052242': {'lengthkm': 1.555787, 'uparea': 123.23709555834532, 'order': 2, 'strmDrop_t': 231.5, 'unitarea': 123.23709555834532, 'Q': 1.569334612348277}, '21009006': {'lengthkm': 6.677901703662528, 'uparea': 493.8188826654188, 'order': 2, 'strmDrop_t': 5.3, 'unitarea': 36.89608111068623, 'Q': 5.309544598741915}}
```

Note the newly added `Q` values in output.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, which method would be more efficient? .keys() like you proposed or .items() like @AloneTogether wrote down here?

Comment: `for k in somedict.keys()` is the same as `for k in somedict`, right?

Comment: The answer by @JackDeeth would be more efficient, since we only need to pick values from dict values and mutate itself.

Answer (score 2):

Or with `dict.items()`:

```py
net_info = {
            '17052242':{'lengthkm': 1.555787, 'uparea': 123.23709555834532, 'order': 2,
                        'strmDrop_t': 231.5, 'unitarea': 123.23709555834532},
            '21009006':{'lengthkm': 6.677901703662528,'uparea': 493.8188826654188, 
                        'order': 2,'strmDrop_t': 5.3, 'unitarea': 36.89608111068623}
            }

def discharge(a):
    return 0.0229*pow(a, 0.8781)


for k, v in net_info.items():
    net_info[k]['Q'] = discharge(v['uparea'])
```